# escape or replace double quotes from form-field

Tags: json, asp-classic, escaping

I have a form-field (`textarea`) in my application, which may contain double-quotes (`""`). For a `JSON`-String, I wrote a small "setup", which is send afterwards. I encountered the problem, that if a user uses the double-quotes, my setup breaks.

This is how it looks like so far:

```
dim payload
payload = payload & "{""short_description"":""" & Replace(Replace(trim(shortDesc),chr(10),""), chr(13), "") & ""","
payload = payload & """description"":""" & Replace(Replace(trim(Description),chr(10),""), chr(13), "") &""","
payload = payload & """u_requester"":"""& sgi &""","
payload = payload & """contact_type"":""Self-service"","
payload = payload & """cmdb_ci"":""" & system &""","
payload = payload & """u_category"":""" & category & """}"
```

And just to show you where I'm using it:

```
With http
  Call .Open("POST", url, False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  Call .Send(payload)
End With
```

The variables used in this method are arguments in the current function. 
I thought about escaping double-quotes, but I somehow just end up on sites which suggest I should use `chr(34)` in a `Response.Write`, which isn't what I'm looking for.

I also tried to use the `Replace`-function, similar how I would do this in PHP:

`Replace(myvar, '"'; "'")`

But as you may figured out, a single-quote starts a comment in classic ASP. How can I get rid off the double-quotes here? It doesn't really matter if I convert `"` to `'` or keep the double-quotes. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you need a visible double quote within a string in asp, you need to double it.

```
Response.Write("""")
```

If you want to replace a double quote,

```
str = Replace(str,"""","")
```

Answer (score 0):

to display a double quote (or single quote) in a json string, you need to escape it:

```
str = "this is a ""test""."
strForJson = Replace( str, """", "\""" )
```